# python return largest integer in the list

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and am trying to work with lists.
how can i get my function to accept a list of integers and then returns the largest integer in the list?

Answer (score 21):

Use [the built-in `max` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
>>> L=[2,-7,3,3,6,2,5]
>>> max(L)
6
```

If you want to use `max` in a custom function, you could do this:

```
def getMaxOfList(L):
    return max(L)
```

I don't know why you would want to do this though, since it provides absolutely no new functionality

If you want to write your own implementation of `max`:

```
def myMax(L):
    answer = None
    for i in L:
        if i > answer:
            answer = i
    return answer
```

Comment: @sberry: `max` already *does* take a list argument. Or a tuple argument. Or a set. Or whatever crazy iterable you have. Why would you wrap it in anything?

Comment: Would anybody like to tell me why I get a -1?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Your answer uses a wrapper function that serves only to confuse newbies about the distinctions between built-in and user-defined functions.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: your code does not work in Python 3, as you cannot compare `None` and numbers using `>`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: Sorry, this was python2.x code

Comment: @user2357112: I added the wrapper function by request from sberry. I believe you responded to that comment, after which s/he seems to have deleted it

Comment: how can i make this program take a list? without using the max function? my function is : def getLargest

Comment: @user2627901: Look at the last option in my post

Comment: it will only let me take one argument though.

Comment: @user2627901: and that one argument is your list

Answer (score 1):

use `max` function:

```
>>> L=[2,-7,3,3,6,2,5]
>>> L
[2, -7, 3, 3, 6, 2, 5]
>>> max(L)
6
```